# Laravel add select query returning wrong result

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im running this query and the result I'm getting isn't what it's supposed to be.

```
$query = DB::table('table');
//for
$query->addSelect($columns[$i]);
//endfor
$query->where('column','=','something')->get();
```

Whenever I `var_dump($query);`

I get way too much text randomly and the page is crashing.

Whenever I `var_dump(count($query));`

I get the result: `int(1)`
but the result should be 2 in my case.
Whenever I run the query in phpmyadmin, it shows me 2 results. I know the query is right cause I check by making a mistake in a column name and it gives me an error with the full query and what column is wrong. So I copy and paste that query to phpmyadmin and remove the mistake I made in a column name. The result in phpmyadmin is perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the result of the query:

```
$query = DB::table('table');
//for
    $query->addSelect($columns[$i]);
//endfor
$result = $query->where('column','=','something')->get();
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This fixed it. Al though I dont get it. With a normal `$query = DB::table('table')->get();` you can just use `$query`.

Comment: Exactly. Notice how you are doing `$query = `. You could do that here as well - `$query = $query->where('column','=','something')->get();` Because now `$query` is equal to whatever `->get()` is returning.